# I am getting this error "Relevent error causing widget was Scaffold " after introducing indexed stack widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Ok, so i am building a wallet app on flutter and i want a bottom navigation bar with three icons, so i used indexed stack on the main home screen and converted all other pages into a list of widgets in the variable pages.
After introducing the indexed stack ,i am getting so many errors like from that of the title

I tried and found that (maybe wrong )the error maybe because of the conflict of framework in finding the
desired location , maynot be wrapped with MaterialApp widget

here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mytodo/screens/quick_send.dart';

import 'package:mytodo/screens/wallet_screen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _currentPage = 0;
  List<Widget> pages = const [HomeScreen(), QuickSend(), WalletScreen()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentPage,
        children: pages,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _currentPage = value;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: _currentPage,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
        unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.green),
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Home",
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home_rounded,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.monetization_on_outlined,
              ),
              label: "Payment"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.wallet),
            label: "Wallet",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is using `HomeScreen` inside

```dart
 List<Widget> pages = const [HomeScreen(), //<- this one
```

You can replace this widget your home view widget.

```dart
 List<Widget> pages = const [Text("My Home View"), QuickSend(), WalletScreen()];
```